# Correct way to get a GTX 980 working in Ubuntu 15.10 x64

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 15.10

I have a GTX 980 EVGA. I have been trying to get it to work with Ubuntu 15.10. I have been having very bad luck doing so. I've tried the driver manager built into Ubuntu, that was a no go. I tried a PPA that i read from another forum, that didnt work either. Also i uninstalled the drivers and got the latest from nVidia's website which got me farther to the login screen and then it locked up. Any thoughts?

System specs:
Intel core i5 6600k
ASUS Z170 deluxe
16gb DDR4 3200 in XMP mode
GTX 980 SC EVGA ACX 2.0

Tried in UEFI and legacy mode. No go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per nvidia's website - the matching driver is nvidia-361 for your graphics card. It's the same for my graphics card(mine is GTX 950M)

First uninstall the currently installed NVIDIA drivers.
Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official stable NVIDIA drivers.
Boot the computer, when the GRUB menu appears ...

Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and press the E key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press F10 to boot the Ubuntu operating system.

When the login screen appears press Ctrl+Alt+F1.
Enter your user name and the password, then execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Note :
Maybe it is explicitly necessary to select the NVIDIA adapter in BIOS.
When you want to use drivers 361, adding the PPA is not necessary.
In this case the terminal commands you have to perform are these :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Also if you have installed the proprietary drive from nvidia site...better to uninstall it as per the installation instructions. I have the similar kind of laptop and opensource drive is working fine for me.

Comment: thank you! that worked. However with 3 monitors hooked up it refuses to boot, it locks on the "z" screen. with 2 LCD's it boots fine. 2 LCDs are on the digital ports, and the other is on a VGA to DVI.

Comment: Nvidia's site was directing me to use the 375.26 version of Linux 64-bit which did not work - however version 361 did, thanks!

Comment: @joe. Glad that this works for you. I have Nvidia GeForce GT601 card and using nvidia-367 successfully.