# Problem with installing Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows-10

I was following this guide http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html and encountered the problem below:

After disabling fastboot and rebooting with the UEFI USB Device (the USB drive I created using Win32DiskImager), I entered the GRUB screen, selected "try Ubuntu without installing" and hit enter. What happened next is that the screen turned black and stayed that way forever. I can tell the computer was still running though.

Any idea on what might be the issue here? I've already tried many things, including re-imaging the Ubuntu iso file to different usb sticks, trying out different versions like 14.x and 15.x, etc., but none of them works.

Any suggestions/help will be much appreciated!

Update with more details:

It's a desktop with NVIDIA GTX 980 Ti. Not quite sure about the USB ports - it says "ss" and I looked in the device manager and found "Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub".

Comment: Laptop model? GPU model? Are you using USB 3.0 ports?

Comment: When you try Ubuntu and the screen is black, does waiting five minutes help? After the five minute wait, if the screen is still black, does pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 do anything?

Comment: probably a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/738377/correct-way-to-get-a-gtx-980-working-in-ubuntu-15-10-x64

Comment: @Olathe I just tried pressing ctrl+alt+F1 after 5 minutes of wait - still black screen

Comment: @ubfan1 I looked at the other question and it seems to be quite different - the other person already installed Ubuntu and only had problems with the video card, while I have not been able to install Ubuntu yet

Comment: @AndroidDev It's a desktop with NVIDIA GTX 980 Ti. Not quite sure about the USB ports - it says "ss" and I looked in the device manager and found "Generic SuperSpeed USB Hub".

Comment: If UEFI you still boot installer with grub and it needs the nomodeset or nomodeset=0 to get into low quality graphic mode. You really cannot easily install nVidia proprietary driver into live installer, but after install will want to install it. See also screen shot examples for UEFI boot: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it