# Windows 10 UBUNTU bash

Tags: apt, bash, windows

I am having multiple problems getting UBUNTU to work properly..

I am getting pages of errors after running `apt-get install -f`

the errors end with:

```
6b39-1.13.11-0ubuntu0.14.04.1); however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64 is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached alreadydpkg: error 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates-java
 openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64
 openjdk-6-jre-headless:amd64
 udev
 openjdk-7-jre:amd64
 xserver-xorg-core
 xserver-xorg-video-glamoregl
 xserver-xorg-video-r128
 xserver-xorg-video-mach64
 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
 xserver-xorg-video-ati
 xserver-xorg-video-cirrus
 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev
 xserver-xorg-video-intel
 xserver-xorg-video-mga
 xserver-xorg-video-modesetting
 xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
 xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
 xserver-xorg-video-qxl
 xserver-xorg-video-s3
 xserver-xorg-video-savage
 xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion
 xserver-xorg-video-sis
 xserver-xorg-video-sisusb
 xserver-xorg-video-tdfx
 xserver-xorg-video-trident
 xserver-xorg-video-vesa
 xserver-xorg-video-vmware
 xserver-xorg-video-all
 xserver-xorg-input-evdev
 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
 xserver-xorg-input-mouse
 xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
 xserver-xorg-input-wacom
 xserver-xorg-input-all
 xserver-xorg
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao:amd64
 icedtea-6-jre-jamvm:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have very minimal experience with linux!!!!!

I have also downloaded the NVida linux Vulkan graphics drivers but they won't install because of:

```
root@AMDX6CORE:~# ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-364.16.run
ERROR: Temporary directory /tmp is not executable - use the  --tmpdir option to specify a different one.
```

Comment: When you are booting Ubuntu do you receive the terminal or just the terminal window in GUI?

Comment: Clarify your environment - are you working with a Dual Boot setup, or Windows 10 with their 'Linux Bash' features inside the OS?

Comment: I am only getting UBUNTU to work(sort of) in the new Windows 10 bash pre release. When I tried to install it to its own HD it would give the black screen of death after GRUB 2 with no "Ctrl F1" option AND no way to get to a terminal to even try to fix things.

Comment: @WarwickLake The Bash support in Windows Pre-Release is not really fully-fledged Ubuntu, per se, but you should also consider that it is still in a *really really young* 'pre-release' state - it's actually really more pre-Alpha stage - given it looks like everything failed to configure, that's a bug in that environment, and likely should be filed at Windows.

Comment: Hardware: AMD 6CORE 3.2GHZ with NVIDA GTX 780.

Comment: Can't even get UBUNTU to run in its own HD from grub 2 in a seperate install. BIOS not support new HD standared EFEI or whatever it is called.

Comment: I tried to replace UBUNTU with MANJARO and it worked for a couple of days until it updated the OS and then the black screen of death returned with a complete hang on every boot.

Comment: My main linux is on a second hd seperate from win 10.

Comment: Best not to use nVidia's .run file, It has to be reconfigured with every kernel update. To see available versions: `ubuntu-drivers devices` and then install from Ubuntu repository, like this but using recommended verison: http://askubuntu.com/questions/738377/correct-way-to-get-a-gtx-980-working-in-ubuntu-15-10-x64

Comment: when I boot into linux using grub2 i can't even get to a terminal to change the default drivers she crashes every time xwindows tries to load.

Comment: is there a way to add An Emergancy Terminal Boot option from the grub 2 boot menu? EVEN gui SAFE Modes don't work and cause a crash.

Comment: I don't think you can get anything hardware-related like device drivers for Linux to work on Windows. What you're using there to get Linux programs to run is just a software compatibility layer. If you want to toy with Vulkan development you should stick to Windows or install a real Linux next to your Windows. Also… Java 1.6 in 2016? \*shudder\* "1.6" does not stand for the last to digits of the year like in Ubuntu releases, you know.

Answer (score 0):

I found a 90% fix for this problem at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1325142

The following has fixed most(90-95%) of my problems.

(N.B.1)

```
sudo dpkg-divert --local --add /etc/init.d/systemd-logind
```

(N.B.2)

```
sudo ln -s /bin/true /etc/init.d/systemd-logind

(This now works)
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I don't understand why this works
it just does.... Something about an ancient ubuntu BUG that has come back to haunt them......