# Unable to get EVGA GTX 980 SC Working

Tags: nvidia, nouveau

So, I'm running the most recent ubuntu release. I have tried *everything* I can find. No matter what I do, I either cannot get past the login screen, or if I do it freezes up. I am nearly to the point of simply giving up and worrying about playing with linux when I get my laptop for school later this year which has no GPU. Unplugging my GPU the system runs fine - it's very frustrating that it's *so difficult* to get Ubuntu running on a 980.

What I have tried:

- Downloading the proprietary nvidia driver
  361.45.11 from their website and installing it - however I cannot get nouveau to stop despite multiple guides and google searches so the
  driver won't install.
- I've tried using ppa's from various forum posts to install drivers with no success
- I've tried installing nvidia-current
- I've tried installing nvidia-361
- Following each of these attempts I also tried adding both nomodeset and nouveau.modeset=0 to the linux line during boot

I'd really like to have ubuntu working without having to uninstall my GPU every time I want to mess around, but I'm beginning to worry that's not going to happen. If anyone has other ideas that I haven't tried or thinks another linux distro would work better, please let me know. All I know right now is I hate nouveau as it doesn't seem to like Nvidia cards.

Thanks

*EDIT*
If it'll help here are my specs:

- CPU= i5 6600k
- RAM= 16gb Corsair Dominator Platinum DDR4 2300
- MOBO= ASUS Sabertooth Z170s
- GPU= EVGA SC GTX 980

Comment: This solve your problem:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/738377/correct-way-to-get-a-gtx-980-working-in-ubuntu-15-10-x64