# Getting Monitor to Use it's Native 2560x1080 Resolution ; Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, monitor

I have two monitors and it isn't letting me select 2560x1080 for my one monitor when I go into settings. I've searched and found a couple of answers but none seem to fix my issue. I have a Nvidia GPU, though not entirely sure which drivers I have installed.

Comment: You need to have correct nVidia driver, and purge any other drivers first: http://askubuntu.com/questions/738377/correct-way-to-get-a-gtx-980-working-in-ubuntu-15-10-x64 But use this to install newest/correct driver: `ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended ` and then this if correct driver: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`