# what happened to my installed driver?

Tags: 20.04, graphics

I have a new ( 1 year) Dell Alienware laptop which came with an invidia graphics card ( geforce rtx 3040). i removed win 11 and installed ubuntu 20.04. It now says my grahics is mesa intel UHD.  WHere did the nvidia card go, and will I have issues if i upgrade to ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: You probably have two adapters: One Intel and one Nvidia. Ubuntu installation defaulted to Interl graphics. You have to search on Internet or AskUbuntu and learn how to install and use the Nvidia driver.

Answer (score 3):

Check UEFI settings.
You should have one that specifies which graphic chip to use. It may allow auto switching.
Desktop systems, have two different sets of video ports, one on motherboard and other on nVidia card.

If you change to nVidia, you may need the nomodeset boot parameter to boot, until you install the correct nvidia driver.

New versions of Ubuntu have latest driver. You can use Safe boot option & choose restricted drivers when installing.

If you boot using nomodeset or grub's recovery mode in grub menu, you can just install driver. If you previously installed incorrect or different driver you must purge first or you will have conflicts.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

[Installing Ubuntu-mate with dual boot option on Windows 10 - usb booting not happening](https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413)

Older nomodeset instructions you do not now need to add ppa to get recent drivers:

[My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

[Correct way to get a GTX 980 working in Ubuntu 15.10 x64](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738377/correct-way-to-get-a-gtx-980-working-in-ubuntu-15-10-x64)