# Dual Boot Ubuntu Problem/WIn 11 have to reinstall grub everytime

Tags: grub-efi

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.4.3 alongside Win 11. My hardware is a MSI GP66 HX, I7, NVIDIA 3070. After the install everything appeared fine however, after rebooting and selecting ubuntu in the GRUB the screen goes blank. I have found that if i select advacned boot mode and reinstall grub i can then logon. I would hate to have to do this every time. Any ideas??

Comment: When you installed did you select to install optional restricted drivers which is needed for your nVidia card? Advanced mode adds nomodeset to grub to use low quality graphics. At recovery mode and terminal try this: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` If you did instlal the wrong nVidia driver, you must purge first. Only install from Ubuntu's repository, not direct from nVidia. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418211/what-happened-to-my-installed-driver

Comment: Thx, I’ll give it a shot and report back.