# How repair nvidia driver to work?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, graphics

On open nvidia settings get next errors:

```sh
$ sudo nvidia-smi
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
(nvidia-settings:7395): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 19:20:22.799: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: 19:20:22.801: PRIME: Requires offloading
** Message: 19:20:22.801: PRIME: is it supported? yes
** Message: 19:20:22.837: PRIME: Usage: /usr/bin/prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query
** Message: 19:20:22.837: PRIME: on-demand mode: "1"
** Message: 19:20:22.837: PRIME: is "on-demand" mode supported? yes
```

In opened popup selected "NVIDIA On-Demand" option

Below some system information

```
$ uname -a
Linux legion 5.4.0-135-generic #152-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 23 20:19:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
x11

$ mokutil --sb-state
EFI variables are not supported on this system

$ test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo "Legacy(bios)"
Legacy(bios)

$ dkms status
nvidia, 515.86.01, 5.4.0-135-generic, x86_64: installed

$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm           1163264  0
nvidia_drm             61440  0
nvidia_modeset       1146880  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              40820736  11 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        184320  2 nvidia_drm,i915
drm                   495616  15 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm,i915


$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:138 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 630
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 630
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GeForce GTX 1060 Max-Q 3GB
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia

$ nvidia-smi
Mon Dec 19 19:23:22 2022       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.86.01    Driver Version: 515.86.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   42C    P8     4W /  N/A |      2MiB /  3072MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Try reinstall to nvidia-driver-460 - did not help.

The another symptom - VLC stopped working too (open via terminal and try to play mkv/mp4)

```
$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d)
[00005591dce9a670] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[00005591dcf38080] main playlist: playlist is empty
[00005591dcf6ef00] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007f8954d05160] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00005591dcf6ef00] vlcpulse audio output error: digital pass-through stream connection failure: Not supported
[00005591dcf6ef00] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007f8954d05160] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
libva info: VA-API version 1.7.0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_7
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
Killed
```

But Parole media Player works fine, ffmpeg works too

Answer (score 0):

0. Assuming you're NOT using something downloaded from the nvidia webpage (remove anything such by running the installer with an appended <space>`--uninstall`)
1. Hit the Win-key, start typing `software` and a pinkish icon will appear; click on it.
2. Look up `Additional drivers` (a tab at top) and click on it.
3. There should be a set of nvidia driver versions available. Set a tick to the left of one that is NOT selected.
4. Wait for it to complete, then reboot and see if things work better.

**Now note(1):** I ASSUME that *changing* the driver DOES PURGE what there is before. If that isn't so; then you need to do it manually.
That can be done by `$ sudo apt purge PACKAGENAME` until you have all removed.
PACKAGENAME is at least one item in the second column of
`dpkg --list | grep -E '^ii.*nvidia.*'`
... i.e. nvidia packages that remains installed.

**Note(2):** `$ nvidia-smi` does not need `sudo`, normally(?)

Comment: You have to fully purge old driver(s) before attempting to install a new driver, or you get conflicts. purge & install nvidia
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418211/what-happened-to-my-installed-driver & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413