# I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a machine with an Nvidia GPU. What should I do now?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I just built a PC with an Nvidia GeForce RTX 3080 and installed Ubuntu 22.04 (Desktop) on it. What now?

1. Is Ubuntu "seeing" the GPU? By that I mean, will it use the GPU if I do something like play a game or run deep learning?
2. How can I determine what the answer to question (1) is?
3. If I need to do anything to make the answer to question (1) "yes", what are those things?

When I go to Settings/About, the "Graphics" field lists "llvmpipe", which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Note: I've run into specific problems trying to install drivers, and will ask a separate question about that, but I think it will be useful for this site to have a question about this general issue, because I've felt very lost for the past day or so. For example, I say I've run into trouble trying to install drivers, but to be honest I don't even know if I need to install drivers at all, I was just guessing.

Comment: Because the nViidia drive is a binary blob, Ubuntu cannot sign it for Secure boot installs. If using Secure Boot, the user must sign the driver. When installing you should be using Safe Boot and check to install the restricted extras. If Secure Boot is off, it just installs. If you can boot or can boot recovery mode from grub, you can install driver. purge & install nvidia
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418211/what-happened-to-my-installed-driver & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413