# 2204 Clean Install Single OS: Unable to Install grub

Tags: grub2, system-installation, 22.04

I'm trying to do a clean install of 22.04 (previously running 20.04).
No dual boot - Just Ubuntu 22.04.

I downloaded the ISO and created the boot thumbdrive as instructed by Ubuntu.

I boot the machine and I get the install window. So far so good.

I select a Normal Installation

I want the OS to be installed on the SSD installed in the machine so
for "Installation Type" so I select "Something Else" in order to set the partitions.

I set up a /, /boot, swap and efi partitions the same sizes that I've always used.

The EFI partition look like:

/dev/sda7  efi   26060mb

For "Device for boot loader installation" I have:

/dev/sda ATA Samsung SDD 840 (256.1 GB)

It copies the files....

It then moves to "Installing System"

And I get the failure:

Unable to install Grub in /dev/sda

Executing "grub-install /dev/sda failed"
This is a fatal error

I tried selecting /dev/sda7 - the efi partition but that failed as well.

The USB stick is not the first selection in the BIOS boot priority.

I am at a loss as to how to proceed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: 26,000 MB is way too big, try 300MB. Does it have a fat filesystem on it? Are you booting the install stick in UEFI mode?

Comment: I reduced it to 536 (auto-selected by the installer).  When I go into the BIOS the entry for the USB stick does say UEFI. I do not believe the USB stick has a FAT file system if that's what you are asking.  My Desktop is pure Ubuntu - no Windows...no FAT

Comment: Does it matter whether or not the EFI partition is the first partition on the SSD?

Comment: Normally the ESP is first or near beginning of drive. But I think the real requirement is that it be in the first 2TB of a drive. Post this: `sudo parted -l` and `lsblk -e7 -f`

Comment: I'd be happy to report the results of those two commands but I can't: I replaced the SSD drive in case that was faulty and also moved the efi partition to the start of the drive and made its size = 536mb. The install went fine. BUT NOW... I have no display. All monitors are black.

Comment: Nvidia? Did you install the restricted/proprietary drivers? That is a check box during install. At grub menu use second line or recovery mode, turn on Internet & install driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it purge & install nvidia
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418211/what-happened-to-my-installed-driver

Comment: Hi oldfred - thanks for your help by the way.  I tried installing both ways - clicking on install drivers and 3rd party, and not clicking on it. No good. Black screen either way. All my screens light up with the jellyfish display during the install so the basic video card/screens work

Comment: You've not said what system you're actually trying to install. You do mention 22.04 but various installers exist for 22.04 which are selected by the ISO but you've not said. Are you trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop? , Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server? or a *flavor* as a comment makes me think you're using the `calamares` installer.  Also if 22.04 or 22.04.1 (as installer version can differ for some ISOs).  Please be specific.

Comment: Ok sorry.  I'm trying to install 22.04.01 LTS Desktop.  I downloaded the 22.04.01 Desktop ISO from Ubuntu and verified the download via the Ubuntu procedure.  Then used Startup Disk Creator to store the ISO onto the thumbdrive.  If there's anything else you need to know just let me know.

Comment: After the install is complete, it says that I have to restart the machine But, unlike past distros, it does not tell me I have to remove the USB drive first.  Then  on booting, it does file system checks,  this message flashes on the screen briefly:  mnt device must be supplied (device name is empty).  But then it's black screens. I can successfully boot off of the USB drive.

Comment: Ok the original issue - install failing because: "Unable to install Grub in /dev/sda" is fixed. The problem was a bad SSD - I replaced it and the problem went away. Now I'm dealing with the black screen/nvidia problem I went to the we pages old fred suggested and I have one screen (out of 3) working.  The OS does not d=see the other two and upon boot I get the message: drm:nv_drm_load [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice.     I suspect this is still a driver issue so I[m pursuing that. Thanks to everyone for the help I've gotten so far.