# Black screen after updating of nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I use Kubuntu 20.04 and have GTX 1080 TI. I decided to update videocard drivers and after that I have an issue.
When I try to load the system I faced with black screen (without cursor). I tried to remove drivers and after that I could see all gui interfaces (but couldn’t use some features like nvenc). Then I have tried to reinstall nvidia drivers and again faced with black screen.
I have tried to install different versions of the drivers but always I saw black screen after that.
Every time when I removed drivers I could use my system. But then I have downloaded drivers from nvidia site, not from repository, and tried to install by .sh file. Now I see black screen and can’t remove the drivers by apt remove nvidia*.
Can someone help me with it?

Maybe it will help:

```
$ sudo modprobe nvidia -vv
modprobe: INFO: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:892 kmod_module_insert_module() Failed to insert module '/lib/modules/5.4.0-135-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko': Operation not permitted
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Operation not permitted
```

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Can't open display
```

```
$ lspci | grep "VGA"
26:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
```

```
$ sudo systemctl enable nvidia
Failed to enable unit: Unit file nvidia.service does not exist.
```

I also tried to add `nomodeset` in grub but this is can't help.

Comment: Can you boot recovery mode? Did you purge old driver? Otherwise you get conflicts and nothing works. From recovery mode enable Internet & at terminal purge & install correct driver. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418211/what-happened-to-my-installed-driver & https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

Comment: @oldfred when I installed drivers from repository I can purge drivers and load the system, but after I installed the drivers from file which I downloaded from nvidia site I can't delete them.

Comment: This is the problem when trying to install drivers manually. You have to install them from the repository using `apt-get`. 

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-22-04 

This article is for ubuntu 22.04. But no difference from 20.04. So you can use this. But be careful. This article writer's Nvidia is made for driver-470. You have to be careful about that. Find out what is your device compatibel drive by following the article.

Comment: If you do not install the drivers from Ubuntu's repository,  you have reinstall with every kernel update as they have not been modified to integrate into the kernel. Best not to use the .run from nVidia. Uninstall the .run nVidia driver.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers

Comment: As I wrote earlier, I first installed drivers from the official repository, after which I encountered a black screen. After removing the drivers with `apt purge nvidia*` I was able to boot the operating system but only using nouveau. Only after several attempts to install drivers through the repository, I tried to install using the .run file downloaded from the nvidia site.

Comment: Now I tried to uninstall the driver using the same .run file, but I see an error: "There is no NVIDIA driver currently installed." When I try to remove it with `sudo apt purge nvidia*` I get an error: "Unable to locate package nvidia.log Couldn't find any package by glob 'nvidia.log'". However, when I try to install using `ubuntu-drivers install` I see a message that nvidia drivers 525 are already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why Ubuntu did not turn on with nvidia drivers was found. The fact is that Secure Boot was enabled in BIOS. After turning it off, the system works without problems.
But I have not yet checked how Windows 10 will behave with Secure Boot disabled. I hope all will be ok.

Comment: Please 'Accept' your own answer here, this will indicate to others that this answer solved your issue...

Answer (score 0):

I solved a same issue, with a specific case (risers, GPUs x5, new motherboard).

[I shared my experience here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1460171/1128161).