# Ubuntu 22.04 not booting after I installed nvidia drivers

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, 22.04

Today I installed new proprietary and tested nvidia drivers for Ubuntu 22.04. Kernel 5.15. After the grub screen the logs showed

```
ACPI BIOS Error (bug): could not resolve symbol [\_TZ.ETHD]
```

Than the screen goes black.

Is there a way to fix it by installing the drivers from life USB?
Thanks for any leads

Nvidia is GTX 1660Ti

Comment: The ACPI error is probably not a problem, lots of those with later kernels.  Have you tried recovery or safe mode when booting?  Look at the grub menu and if not an option, look under the "advanced" choice for more items.

Comment: What do you mean by screen is black?

Is screen black and you see no boot messages even after jamming on the escape key?

Is the screen black after it boots?

Are you stuck on a terminal prompt?

The ACPI message you see there happens with EVERY nvidia driver due to the proprietary nature of their software. That's not a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you using the proprietary NVIDIA driver make sure to turn off **Secure boot** in your UEFI.

This [has been asked](https://askubuntu.com/q/1446984/906933) two weeks ago and should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time with the same issue, with a specific case.

My config : new ROG Strix B550-F motherboard, 5 GPUs (3090 x2, 3070 x3, using riser to connect thoses on motherboard), CPU Ryzen 7 5900X.

BIOS ver 3002

This could also affect anyone using risers for GPUs with new motherboards.

**1. Disable Secure Boot**

[Old version BIOS](https://www.technewstoday.com/how-to-enable-secure-boot-on-asus/#ez-toc-container).

Latest BIOS version in "Boot > Secure Boot > Key Management", erase the secure boot key (back up it before if necessary, with the option "Save all Secure Boot Variables").

[image: Disable Secure Boot]

**2. Change PCIe mode**

In "Advanced > Onboard Devices Configuration".

I forced it to PCIe Gen2.

**Auto mode will not work properly with risers.** ([More in this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/buildapc/comments/jl4sa6/solution_for_no_boot_with_3070_plugged_into_pcie/)).

[image: Change PCIe mode]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).