# Internet and bluetooth not working with ROG Strix B550-F on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: internet, motherboard

**The problem**
So I changed my NVIDIA driver version to one that I know for sure works because I previously used it. I rebooted my computer and the wifi and bluetooth could not be detected. I originally thought it could be a wifi card problem but ethernet also does not work.

**What I've tried**

- Plugging in a wifi adapter and bluetooth adapter, those don't work either.
- For some reason, the computer doesn't recognize exFat formatted drives anymore either, which it did before.

Comment: It looks like you did something wrong with your kernel. Modules are not installed. Try to boot with a previous kernel. Also please add information on what exactly you did with Nvidia drivers.

Comment: How do I boot with a previous kernel?

Comment: You can use grub menu fro that,

Comment: Installing Nvidia drivers from `.run` files is wrong for Ubuntu. It may cause a lot of trouble, it will be hard to fix, if you don't have some knowledge.

Comment: using a different kernel via grub did not work

Comment: Did you check for any firmware/BIOS updates for the B550?

Comment: looks like there is: https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-b550-f-gaming-wi-fi-model/helpdesk_bios/

Comment: You need to purge any previous nVidia and uninstall any .run files. Only then can you install a new nVidia driver. You may need to boot recovery mode or manually add nomodeset boot parameter. Is UEFI Secure boot on? Updating UEFI firmware may change settings to turn on UEFI Secure boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418211/what-happened-to-my-installed-driver & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

Comment: @oldfred I purged the NVIDIA drivers and was able to install another one I was using however the newest one just errors out in the ubuntu gui app, no error messsage. I also don't see a UEFI anything in the BIOS.

Comment: I can't get the latest driver for NVIDIA after setting `nomodeset` because I can't connect to the internet.

Comment: I don't think this is a driver issue though. Switching drivers must have messed something up somehow though.

Comment: If you boot recovery mode, you get a command line & old fashioned menu. One is to turn on internet & other is terminal where you can purge nVidia & reinstall nVidia version. A new driver does not automatically uninstall or fully overwrite an old driver. So purge always required before new install.

Comment: @oldfred, so boot into the recovery mode kernel? And then turn on internet? Is that what you recommend I do?

Comment: Yes, it that does not work then another question on Internet issues. Are you using WiFi or hardwired Ethernet? Until correct wireless driver installed, better to use Ethernet.

Comment: I wrote this question that came from this one (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450276/unclaimed-network-network-ethernet-controller-how-to-claim). But bluetooth also does not work and can't read exFat file systems so I think there is a bigger issue.

Comment: Each of those is really a separate question. But driver for WiFi probably is driver for bluetooth. ExFat is a Microsoft proprietary format. Linux not has driver, but you may have to install that also. Best not to use Microsoft formats in Linux. And if sharing a partition better to use NTFS. ExFAT has no journal and can make repairs more difficult or impossible. Its intended for small devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a kernel issue, changing the driver *can sometimes* modify the kernel in such a way to where it corrupts some of the modules. This question/answer: [UNCLAIMED network (network/ethernet controller). How to claim?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1450276/unclaimed-network-network-ethernet-controller-how-to-claim/1450351#1450351) highlight what I had to do to fix it.