# Ubuntu 22.04 not recognizing/using NVIDIA RTX 3050 GPU, black screen on boot (sometimes), external monitors not being recognized and/or used

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors

I'm running an Dell XPS 17 laptop. This is a dual boot with Windows 11. The graphics card is recognized on Windows but not Ubuntu.

[image: More specific specs]

In Ubuntu my Nvidia drivers are up to date.

[image: pic]

In the *About* -> *Graphics* tab, it says: "llvmpipe (LLVM 13.0.1, 256 bits)" even though it is not my graphics card.

`nvidia-smi` gives `no devices were found` .

`journalctl --catalog --boot | grep nvidia` gives the following results:

[image]

Shortly after updating my drivers on reboot I would get a black screen with a blinking cursor, but for the past five times I've rebooted, that hasn't been an issue, although now it cannot find my two external monitors or the correct GPU.

I've tried purging all of the Nvidia driver packages and reinstalling them, which has not worked.

Do you have any ideas on how to get Ubuntu to recognize/use my dedicated GPU, connect to my monitors, and not get stuck at a black screen at boot time?

Comment: Do you have UEFI Secure Boot on? If so you have to create a MOK or machine owner key (you have to authorize the binary blob is secure). Are these the commands you ran? [purge & install nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418211/what-happened-to-my-installed-driver)