# Ubuntu 23.04 installation problem in Z370 Aorus Gaming 3 rev 1.1

Tags: nvidia, kernel, gigabyte

could anyone help me with the following?

I'm a Ubuntu lover,

On my Desktop PC, I can run all Ubuntu versions up to **22.10**. However, when I tried to install **Ubuntu 23.04**, I encountered an issue during installation. Even if I install **Ubuntu 22.10** first and then try to upgrade to **23.04**, I still encounter the same issue. Additionally, **Even I faced this problem** if I attempting to install **Fedora Workstation 38** also. The issue persists in both cases. It could be the reason for latest Kernel update, I don't know actually.

**The issue is given below.**

```
[0.144417] x66/cu: SGX disabled by BIOS

[4.161053] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolue symbol I\_SB.PCIO.SATO.PRT._GTF.DSSP1, AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)

[4.161178] ACPI Error: Aborting method S_SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTA.
GTF due to preuious error (AE_ NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse 529)

[4.161622] API BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol ISB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO._GTF.DSSPJ,AE_NOT_FOUND(20221020/psarys-330)

[4.161744] ACPI Error: Aborting method. USB PCION SATO PRTO.GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT _FOUND) (20221020/psparse 529)

[4.162053] ACPI-BIOS Erpor (bug : Could not-resolve symbol I_SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTS._GTF.DSSPI, AE_NOT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)

[4.162175] ACPI Error: Aborting nethod _SB.PCIO.SATO.PRIS._GIF due to previous error (AE_NDT_FOUND) (20221020 psparse-529)

[4.163590] ACPI BIOS Error (hug): Could not resolve sumbol I_SB.PCIO.SATO,PRT._GTF.DSSPI,AE_NOT_FOUND(20221020/psargs-330)

[4.163713] ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.PCIO.SATO.PRT._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-5292)

[4.168442] ACPI BIOS Error (bug) : Could not resolve symbol E_SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTO._GTF.DSSPI,AE_NDT_FOUND(20221020/psargs-330)

[4.168565] ACPI Error: Aborting method S_SB.PCIO.SATO.PRIO._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)

[4.172139] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolue symbol E_SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTS._GTF.DSSPI, AE_NDT_FOUND (20221020/psargs-330)

[4.172261] ACPI Error: Aborting method _SB.PCIO.SATO.PRTS._GTF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20221020/psparse-529)
```

[image]

**My PC benchmark is also here:**

**CPU**:

- **Number of cores**       6
- **Number of threads** 12
- **Manufacturer**      GenuineIntel
- **Name**          Intel Core i7 8700K
- **Codename**      Coffee Lake
- **Specification**     Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz

**Motherboard**:

- Z370 AORUS Gaming 3 (0x00000564 - 0x9CF8F233)
- **Manufecturer** Gigabyte Technology Co Ltd.

**SMBIOS Version**          3.1

**BIOS (Updated to Latest Version)**

- **vendor**            American Megatrends Inc.
- **version**           F15
- **date**          11/13/2021
- **ROM size**      16384 KB

**RAM**: 64GB DDR4

**Graphics-Card** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Does system boot? Most ACPI errors and AE_NOT_FOUND errors are not critical, really just warnings. Often vendors do not follow standards & kernel does not implement all of them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.

No, the system doesn't boot, and it always shows only this black screen.

I agree with you that ACPI errors and AE_NOT_FOUND are not critical issues. They were also present during the installation of the previous version of Ubuntu, but after a while, they disappeared, and the system booted correctly, allowing me to install the OS.

 However, in version 23.04, the black screen issue persists and doesn't go away.

Comment: Did you install the restricted drivers as part of install, so nVidia driver was installed? Or can you press escape and get grub menu. Then boot recovery mode & install nVidia driver with Internet on & from terminal? [purge & install nvidia](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418211/what-happened-to-my-installed-driver) &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

Comment: Hi,
I have an update regarding this problem. When using safe-graphics mode, I was able to successfully install Ubuntu 23.04 on my device. I believe I now understand the issue.

The problem seems to be related to my Graphics card. I am hopeful that the maintainers will provide an update with a fix for this soon.

After completing the installation, I rebooted the system and accessed the terminal using the advanced options. However, the problem with launching the desktop mode still remain.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions or solutions to this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, but I'm not sure if it's a good one. My device's performance is not as good as it used to be, but it's acceptable.

1. I installed Ubuntu 23.04 using safe-graphics mode without installing any 3rd party graphics libraries.
2. After installation, during startup, I edited the boot option by pressing **[e]**, and I added nomodeset at the end of this line: `linux /boot/vmlinuz-x.x..../..`
3. The PC started without graphics, and then I downloaded the NVIDIA graphics driver (NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-535.86.05.run) from the official site.
4. I ran the following commands in the terminal:

- `sudo apt install build-essential libglvnd-dev pkg-config`
- `sudo telinit 3`

6. Navigating to the Download directory, I made the NVIDIA driver executable with the command: `sudo chmod +x ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-535.86.05.run`, and then I installed it using: `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-535.86.05.run`
7. The installation was successful, and the Graphics driver was automatically enabled in the X-Server config (No manual intervention needed during installation; it prompted me for this), and I also installed the 32-bit package library when prompted.
8. I rebooted again and started the desktop using the same approach by adding nomodeset as described in step 2.
9. To make the nomodeset setting permanent, I updated grub by running: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`, and I added nomodeset to **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT**. For example, I added: **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"**.
10. Press ctrl-x to save and exit.
11. Execute "sudo update-grub" and wait for it to finish.

Then Reboot the system.

Please suggest me anything important, if I missed or If I did wrong.
Any suggestions will be highly appreaciable.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Best not to use the .run file directly from nVidia. Ubuntu has the latest drivers soon after they are available in its repository. The nVidia .run has to be, in effect reinstalled with every kernel update to integrate it into the kernel. The Ubuntu version does that automatically. Best to install driver as part of install. Or at terminal as shown in comments above.

Comment: Hi @oldfred
Thanks for your good suggestions.

Comment: You have to use the .run file (somehow) to remove it before installing the driver from Ubuntu repository or else you have conflicts. Similar to using purge to remove an incorrect or changed driver from Ubuntu repository. And if you permanently add nomodeset, then you will never use the nVidia driver. Nomodeset is just for setting a default driver, nouveau will is for older cards or default settings to get some video.